# Excel: highlight groupings of data differently based on a cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider a sheet with a bunch of values grouped together. The goal is to have Excel **shade the entire row's background color differently** for each differing group of **Requisition**.

The color is not important. There could be 500 different color changes. I suspect the normal use case is around manually choosing the color. Given that the number of color changes is unknown, it may be hard to automate.

How can I best show logical groupings of rows in Excel? My first attempt was by row color, but perhaps there's a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the color thing, you could automate by using two different colors, one for one group, other for the next group.

You can use the a little macro to achieve this.

```
Sub SetCustomColors()

    Dim color As OLE_COLOR
    Dim color1 As OLE_COLOR
    Dim color2 As OLE_COLOR

    Dim currentRequisition As Integer

    color1 = &HF0F0F0 ' RR GG BB
    color2 = &HF0F000 ' RR GG BB

    currentRequisition = -1
    For r = 3 To 16
        If currentRequisition <> ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
            currentRequisition = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
            color = IIf(color = color1, color2, color1)
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 4)).Interior.color = color
    Next

End Sub
```